# How to copy a Ubuntu repository on a hard disk?

Tags: localrepository

I am a social worker living deep in rural Liberia/West Africa since 2012. My friends and neighbours - eager to "get busy on computers" - love Ubuntu because of its safety features and easy use. However, our internet is so slow that every update or new software becomes a matter of days instead of minutes. We only have GPRS-connection, and stable only in the morning hours...

Is there a way to copy a whole repository on a harddrive? I am not an expert, more a "good user" -- kindly share your ideas not too technically! Any leads are highly appreciated!

Best, Sebastian.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

you can use apt on cd for more detials follow link
http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/doc-manual.html
youtube tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT8mSYdYuO8

Comment: Could you give a little more detail about how this would work in your post?